# How can i imports an aot module (umd) in jit application?

Tags: angular, angular-aot

Code

```
import { ThridModule } from 'thrid-module'; // This is a aot compile module on `window` object with `umd`
@NgModule({
    imports: [ CommonModule, ThridModule ],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

When I run this, I got an error **Unexpected value 'ThridModule' imported by the module 'AppModule'. Please add a @NgModule annotation.**

How can I solve this?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this issue?

Comment: Haven't found a solution yet